# IIS doesn't appear to be using a defaultProxy defined in machine.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET Web API running locally which I'm debugging with Fiddler. The API is running under an application pool account and makes a number of calls out to an external API.

When I run an acceptance test against my local API and capture requests in Fiddler I don't see those external requests, just the HTTP calls made directly within the test's app domain. Having done some reading I see that I need to [configure IIS to use a default proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp) to route all traffic through Fiddler.

So, I tried adding this to my web.config's `system.net`:

```
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
```

This works well. Fiddler now shows me all the internal HTTP requests being made by the API. However, I don't want to affect other developers by committing this web.config change, so I tried moving this section to my machine.config.

Having done this, even though I can see the configuration being pulled through to my IIS application (screenshot below), I don't see the same requests in Fiddler which suggests to me the proxy is not being used. Even after an `iisreset`.

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on this?

**Update 1**

@lex-li pointed out that `usesystemdefault` in my screenshot is `true` whereas I'd set it to `false` in machine.config. It seems this particular value is not pulled through to the application configuration from machine.config for some reason. However, if I override just that value in web.config as below, the application still doesn't use the proxy.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: In the screen shot "usesystemdefault" is "true", so are you sure you modify the correct `machine.config`? There are multiple of them on your machine for different .NET Framework version and bitness.

Comment: Yes, definitely. When I remove `defaultProxy` node from the machine.config in question and refresh the IIS site's configuration the values in the screenshot like `proxyaddress` are now empty. But it's a good spot - let me look at why that particular attribute value isn't being pulled from machine.config.

Comment: Like I said, there are multiple `machine.config` on a machine. IIS Manager only reads one of them (depends on which IIS version you use), while your application, however, can definitely read another. Thus, the first thing to do is to understand how `machine.config` works and which file is used by your application. Then you know how to modify and test it.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET 4.5.2 application targeting any CPU running on a 64-bit Windows 10, so the machine.config it's using is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config unless I'm missing something? And like I say, I can see changes in the machine.config being pulled through to the IIS application's config in the IIS GUI. I've just checked, and it would seem `usesystemdefault` is not an attribute supported when being read from machine.config. Interestingly, when I override that property to false in IIS (which updates my web.config obvs) the proxy is still not used.

Comment: IIS Manager uses its own schema system to manipulate ASP.NET configuration system, so there are by design gaps and possible issues. You should only modify machine.config manually in an editor and then perform the following testing.

Comment: Also when you are editing the machine.config file, make sure you are running your editor as an Administrator. Otherwise you may not be editing the file used by the IIS process, but a sandboxed version.